# Unable to insert buffer in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, buffer, multer

I am trying to make a pdf uploading/downloading application using node, MongoDB, Mongoose and Multer.
while adding new files, I am unable to store the buffer value to database .

here is upload function :

```
function upload(file,body){
    var pdf = fs.readFileSync(file.path);
    var encode_pdf = pdf.toString('base64');
    var dat = Buffer.from(encode_pdf);
    var fin = new Paper({
    _id:new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    subject:body.sub,
    code:body.code,
    slot:body.slot,
    exam:body.exam,
    year:body.year,
    shortform:body.shortform,
    data:dat
    }) ;
```

Schema :

```
var paperSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    subject : String,
    code:String,
    slot : String,
    exam : String,
    year : String,
    shortform : {
        required:false,
        type:String
    },
    filename : String,
    data:Buffer
});
```